# Live dashboard for presentations

Tags: ms-office, keynote, dashboard

I run my school's theatre, and I'm looking for some kind of software that we can put on the projector screen before our school assembly. I want to have some elements update themselves automatically (for example; local weather forecast, time/date, news ticker), and some elements that I can edit myself (to insert school announcements, sports games results, etc).

Powerpoint/Keynote would be perfect because of their customizability, except neither of them allow you to insert live data (weather, news, etc) (Powerpoint Windows does, but not for mac).

Does anyone know of some (mac compatible) software or a website that has this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Dashing](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/) for this. It's a web framework, so you can view the dashboards on any web browser.